# Titanium Appcelerator App (IOS) publishing issue

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

Hi I have uploaded my app to iTunes connect. The app is validated and submitted successfully. While publishing the app to the app store my app got rejected because of **insufficient meta data**

can any one tell me the reason for the same and what changes do I require to make to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have not yet encountered that rejection reason but I think this is not about the app itself. I guess with meta data they mean the information that you provide in iTunes Connect that will be published in the App Store. See meta data section in the guidelines and check them all: [App Store Review Guidelines - Meta Data](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#metadata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata rejection means that the description/screenshots/search tags, that us anything apart of the IPA, which you provide in iTunes, is not as per the guideline or is not incomplete.

In the iTunes Resolution Center they will mention that issue in details. If not you can contact them through the chat option and ask for more information. Usually the Resolution Center will provide all the details.

Answer (score 1):

**Insufficient meta data** means you might have provided invalid meta data. There are **17 guidelines given by Apple** for Metadata as given below. Make sure that you are following all of them.

1. Apps or metadata that mentions the name of any other mobile platform will be rejected
2. Apps with placeholder text will be rejected
3. Apps with names, descriptions, screenshots, or previews not relevant to the content and functionality of the App will be rejected
4. App names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be similar, so as not to cause confusion
5. Small and large App icons should be similar, so as to not to cause confusion
6. Apps with App icons, screenshots, and previews that do not adhere to the 4+ age rating will be rejected
7. Apps with Category and Genre selections that are not appropriate for the App content will be rejected
8. Developers are responsible for assigning appropriate ratings to their Apps. Inappropriate ratings may be changed/deleted by Apple
9. Developers are responsible for assigning appropriate keywords for their Apps. Inappropriate keywords may be changed/deleted by Apple
10. Developers who attempt to manipulate or cheat the user reviews or chart ranking in the App Store with fake or paid reviews, or any other inappropriate methods will be removed from the iOS Developer Program
11. Apps that recommend that users restart their iOS device prior to installation or launch may be rejected
12. Apps should have all included URLs fully functional when you submit it for review, such as support and privacy policy URLs
13. Apps with screenshots, previews, and marketing text that do not clearly identify supplemental content or items that must be purchased separately (e.g. using IAP) will be rejected
14. App previews may only use video screen captures of the app, voice-overs, and textual and design overlays, or the app will be rejected
15. Apps with previews that display personal information of a real person without permission will be rejected
16. App previews may only include music that is licensed for that purpose in all selected territories
17. App previews that include content played or streamed via the app (e.g. iTunes playlist, YouTube streaming video) that is not licensed for use in the preview will be rejected

Finally, you have to make sure that you have provided information about how to use your application so that they can easily test the application.